# How to display Vat Tax & Product Price separately on cart page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, tax

I'm using VAT tax as including in product prices, But on cart page in Subtotal section i want to show original product price + Vat tax as separately. I'm trying but i could not fix this issue. in magento 1 i was fix this issue and working fine but in magento 2 i'm facing this serious issue. please check below images, first image of magento 1 is working fine but in 2nd pic you can see vat is not showing and total order is showing without Vat. I'm using magento 2.1

[image]

[image]